# Design a nonlinear least squares function with multiple local minima

Tags: functions, nonlinear-optimization, least-squares

I need a nonlinear least squares function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which has multiple minima in order to plot it and test some convergence methods using it.

Please note:

The function must be of the form $f = \frac{1}{2} r^2$ where $r: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

I do not want the smallest minimum to be where $f(x) = 0$, it must be a non zero residual problem.

$f(x)$ can not take negative values, but $x$ can be negative.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take e.g. $r(x) = (x-a)^2(x-b)^2 + 1$. It will have two minima (at $x=a$ and $x=b$), and will never be zero (thanks to $+1$ in the end), implying $f$ will never be zero (in particular $f(x) \neq 0$ for the minima). Thus, it satisfies your conditions.

[Live on Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dfw7opg7gc)

---

If you need the function to have different values at different minima, or if you want more than two minima, you can try this approach. Let $x = a_1, \dots, a_n$ be our minima, and $c_1, \dots, c_n \in (0, 1)$ and $d_1, \dots, d_n$ some constants. Define

$$r_i(x) = 1 - (1-c_i)exp(-d_i(x-a_i)^2)$$

$exp(-d_i(x-a_i)^2)$ defines a "bump" with maximum at $a_i$, and $d_i$ controls it's flatness. $r_i$ is this same bump, reversed and scaled so that it takes value $c_i$ at $x=a_i$ and takes the value of $1$ when $x$ is far from $a_i$.

Now, take the product of the $r_i$:

$$r(x) = r_1(x) \cdot r_2(x) \cdots  r_n(x)$$

[Live on Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jo2quy83yi)

Comment: Thanks for this, that works but at the moment the two minima give me the same value for $f(x)$. I should have added that I would ideally like the minima to be different so $f(a) \neq f(b)$. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: @M6126 I've updated the post.

Comment: That's amazing, thanks very much!